# 属性タグによる何番目を取得するかの方法

Tags: google-spreadsheet, xpath

このようなソースがあるとして

```
   <div id = "aaa">
      <div class="name">山田</div>
    </div>
    　～　省略　　～
    <div id = "bbb">
     <p class="name">佐藤</div>
    </div>
    　～　省略　　～
    <div id = "ccc">
     <div class="name">山田</div>
    </div>
```

xpathの指定で属性でclass名がnameに該当するもので
2番目のものを取得したい場合はどうしたらいいしょうか？

要素の番号指定のやり方は
div[2]とかあるとおもいますが属性で絞ることもできるのでしょうか？
//*[@class="name"]　←すべて取得する書き方はわかりましたが・・・

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//*[@class="name"]`をカッコで囲んでその後位置指定の`[2]`（２番目のもの）のように指定すればいいです。

以下例（※提示されたＨＴＭＬの`p`は`div`のタイポであると思われたので修正してあります、あと名前を重複しないように最後の山田を鈴木に変更しました。どちらの山田が得られたのか結果から判別できないため）

```js
var result = document.evaluate( "(//*[@class='name'])[2]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );
//alert(result.singleNodeValue.textContent);//佐藤が得られる
console.log(result.singleNodeValue.textContent);
```

```html
<div id = "aaa">
    <div class="name">山田</div>
</div>
<div id = "bbb">
    <div class="name">佐藤</div>
</div>
<div id = "ccc">
    <div class="name">鈴木</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ()カッコ書きの存在しりませんでした。